# Duplicate the dictionary for each in key value list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python that looks like this:

```
dicts = [{'uid':'12345', 'markets':'['UK', 'US']'},
         {'uid':'55644', 'markets':'['IN', 'SG', 'IE']'}]
```

What I really need is a copy of any dictionary made for each item in the 'markets' list, for each dictionary in the dicts list.  That should look like this:

```
dicts = [{'uid':'12345', 'markets':'['UK']'},
         {'uid':'12345', 'markets':'['US']'},
         {'uid':'55644', 'markets':'['IN']'},
         {'uid':'55644', 'markets':'['IE']'},
         {'uid':'55644', 'markets':'['SG']'}]
```

Can anyone help me understand the best method in Python to solve this?

Comment: are the quotes before the list typo's shouldn't `'['UK', 'US']'` be `['UK', 'US']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will create a list of dictionaries:

```
dicts = [{'uid':'12345', 'markets':['UK', 'US']},
         {'uid':'55644', 'markets':['IN', 'SG', 'IE']}]

def flatten(lists):
    res = []
    for d in lists:
        for market in d['markets']:
            res.append({'uid': d['uid'], 'markets': [market]})

    return res

print flatten(dicts)

# [{'markets': ['UK'], 'uid': '12345'}, {'markets': ['US'], 'uid': '12345'},
#  {'markets': ['IN'], 'uid': '55644'}, {'markets': ['SG'], 'uid': '55644'},   
#  {'markets': ['IE'], 'uid': '55644'}]
```

The code will iterate over dictionaries in the original list. For every dictionary the code will iterate over the markets and for every market it will add a new dictionary to result list. Except the `print` the code will work both on Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: thank you!  what's the best way to write the append line if there are 15+ keys? is writing them out still the best way, if only the 'markets' field changes?

Comment: You could make copy of the current dictionary in the inner loop, assign `market` to  `copy['markets']` and append the copy result list.

Answer (score 0):

You could (python 3) try:

```
dicts = [{'uid':'12345', 'markets':['UK', 'US']},
         {'uid':'55644', 'markets':['IN', 'SG', 'IE']}]


def _split_dict(dict_):
    for country in dict_["markets"]:
        yield {'markets': [country], 'uid': dict_['uid']}


def split_dicts(dicts):
    for dict_ in dicts:
        yield from _split_dict(dict_)


print(list(split_dicts(dicts)))
# [{'uid': '12345', 'markets': ['UK']}, {'uid': '12345', 'markets': ['US']}, {'uid': '55644', 'markets': ['IN']}, {'uid': '55644', 'markets': ['SG']}, {'uid': '55644', 'markets': ['IE']}]
```